# How do I make a post request with proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, proxy

I am new and I don't know how to make a post request with a proxy in node.js. I tried many methods but nothing works...

I have the proxy host, port, username and password.

How do I do this in node.js?

example: I want to make a post request to http://example.com sending this object {"a": 3} using a proxy.

Thank you a lot for any advice / help.

Comment: You make the request to the proxy server instead, and put the authorization into the request header.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
const got = require('got');
const tunnel = require('tunnel');

(async () => {
    const { body } = await got.post("example.com", {
        json: {
            "a": 3
        },
        responseType: 'json',
        agent: {
            https: await tunnel.httpsOverHttp({
                proxy: {
                    host: "proxy host",
                    port: 0,
                    proxyAuth: "user:pass"
                },
            }),
        }
    });
    console.log(body);
})();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't know if you see that this is the answer to my own question but if you do I don't really know how to improve it do I need to delete it?

Comment: The answer does not need to be deleted, only improved. Simply, include a small sentence explaining what the code does and how it helped you.